# Export and Download a list to csv file using Python

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
lista.append(rede)
```

When I print it , is showing:

```
[{'valor': Decimal('9000.00'), 'mes': 'Julho', 'nome': 'ALFANDEGA 1'}, {'valor': Decimal('12000.00'), 'mes': 'Julho', 'nome': 'AMAZONAS SHOPPING 1'}, {'valor': Decimal('600.00'), 'mes': 'Agosto', 'nome': 'ARARUAMA 1'}, {'valor': Decimal('21600.00'), 'nome': 'Rede Teste Integra\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'}, {'valor': Decimal('3000.00'), 'mes': 'Agosto', 'nome': 'Mercatto Teste 1'}, {'valor': Decimal('5000.00'), 'mes': 'Agosto', 'nome': 'Mercatto Teste 2'}, {'valor': Decimal('8000.00'), 'nome': 'Rede Teste Integra\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o 2'}]
```

I would like to export to csv file and download it, could you help me?

Comment: Have a look at the Python CSV module. Also, a minimal show of  effort would go a long way to get help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to transform your data to csv :

```
def Decimal(value):
    #quick and dirty deal with your Decimal thing in the json
    return value

data = [{'valor': Decimal('9000.00'), 'mes': 'Julho', 'nome': 'ALFANDEGA 1'}, {'valor': Decimal('12000.00'), 'mes': 'Julho', 'nome': 'AMAZONAS SHOPPING 1'}, {'valor': Decimal('600.00'), 'mes': 'Agosto', 'nome': 'ARARUAMA 1'}, {'valor': Decimal('21600.00'), 'nome': 'Rede Teste Integra\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'}, {'valor': Decimal('3000.00'), 'mes': 'Agosto', 'nome': 'Mercatto Teste 1'}, {'valor': Decimal('5000.00'), 'mes': 'Agosto', 'nome': 'Mercatto Teste 2'}, {'valor': Decimal('8000.00'), 'nome': 'Rede Teste Integra\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o 2'}]

mes = []
nome = []
valor = []
for i in data:
    mes.append(i.get('mes',""))
    nome.append(i.get('nome',""))
    valor.append(i.get('valor',""))

import csv

f = open("file.csv", 'wt')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow( ('mes', 'nome', 'valor') )
    for i in range(0,len(mes)):
        writer.writerow((mes[i], nome[i], valor[i])) 
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Tks @grubjesic for you quick response, But these data "data" are coming from " lista.append ( rede) " as the data entered in the " list " and turn into a csv file so I can get download directly?

Comment: I am assuming that this data is actually your list.   e.g. rede = {'valor': Decimal('9000.00'), 'mes': 'Julho', 'nome': 'ALFANDEGA 1'}    and that is appended to list named lista  with command : lista.append(rede) .   I am just calling that list (lista) -> data in my example.

Comment: @leonardo santos  were you able to run my code with your data ?